# Reverting blockchain state after each test (Hardhhat isolation Fixture)

Tags: hardhat, testing, brownie

When writing smart contract tests in python (using `Brownie`).
I extensively used `isolation fixture`. This allowed me to isolate test cases from each other.

**Example**:

- We have TokenContract, which upon deployment, mints **1000** tokens for the owner.
- **1. Test** sends **800** tokens from owner => address1 (`Test passes`)
- **2. Test** sends **1000** tokens from owner => address1 (`Test passes`)

The reason both test cases passed is that `isolation fixture` reverts the blockchain after each test, thus the **2.Test**  has a clean/identical setup to the **1.Test**. This ensured that a change in one of the tests couldn't possibly cause an issue in the other test-cases. Something very crucial when you have a large amount of tests.

But at the moment, I am writing tests in `TypeScript` using `Hardhat`, and I can't find anything like `isolation Fixture`. In Hardhat it seems the only way to "isolate" each test case from others is to redeploy the contract (New fresh deployment for each test), which seems too slow and wasteful.

If anybody here has experience in writing and running tests in Hardhat, I would be more than interested to hear how you are dealing/bypassing this limitation.

**NOTE**: If you have example of some good smart contract tests written in TypeScript, I would be interested in taking look.

Comment: Haha I've had this question before but since I didn't find anything, I just kept keeping track of the amount of minted, burned or transferred tokens between tests... Ie. Test 1 mint 100 tokens, test 2 want to mint 1 token, he will have token I'd 101, etc.

Comment: It's really annoying.  Brownie has such well done documentation for this. But I can't find anything similar in regards to Hardhat documentation.